# jquery id in variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a jquery slider, and i am having troubles with one global variable. I can not use it as local in my case. I am using multiple sliders on one page so this global variable EndPosition should be different from slider to slider.

```
$.fn.slider = function(id) {        
    var SliderID = id;
    EndPosition = (VisibleWidth - TotalWidth); //End position for sliding
```

Is there a way to pass an id to variable name, something like EndPosition+id so i can use it like that in other parts of code, for example here

```
if (NewPosition <= EndPosition+id){
                RightNav.addClass('disabled');    
            }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, i will check them now.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using an object and bracket notation:

```
var positions = {
   'endPosition1': 'foo',
   'endPosition2': 'bar'
}

var value = positions['endPosition' + id];
```

In case that your variables are global, you can access them like other properties but this time those are properties of the global `window` object:

```
window['EndPosition' + id];
```

If the `id`s are numeric you can also you a simple array:

```
var positions = ['foo', 'bar'];
positions[id];   
positions[id - 1]; // ?
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be cleaner to use an object to contain your end positions, rather than using multiple global variables:

```
var EndPositions = {};

// ...

EndPositions['id_one'] = 10;
EndPositions['id_two'] = 20;

// ...

if (NewPosition <= EndPositions[id]){
    RightNav.addClass('disabled');    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way (IMO) :

```
$.fn.slider = function(...) {
    // ...
    $(this).data('end-position', visibleWidth - totalWidth);
    // ...
};
```

So if you did

```
$('.slider').slider(...);
```

You can access to the `end-position` variable like this

```
$('.slider').data('end-position');
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to find a slider's end position by id, you can do this this way :

```
<div class="slider" data-id="1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').slider(...);

    ... = $('.slider[data-id=1]').data('end-position');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, you can with:

```
window["EndPosition" + id]
```

so you'd have:

```
   if (NewPosition <= window["EndPosition" + id]) ...
```

`window` is the container for all global vars.

Cheers

Comment: Why do you think the code is running in a global space not in some scope?

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use json array you can do something like this :

```
var sliderObject = [
{ "EndPosition":VisibleWidth - TotalWidth }, 
{ "ID": id  }, 
];
```

And then just check ::

```
NewPosition <= sliderObject [EndPosition][0]
```

Take a look at : http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp